# How to save file as a settings

Tags: 7

How can i use settings form http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7 to make a file saved and retrieved using variable_get() ?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

The settings form does not save entries to a file, but stores the value in the database. It can only be called from a custom module you will have to build.

Below you will find a link to Drupal's own module tutorial. Follow the steps and you will come across the usage of the settings page. (configuration form)

http://drupal.org/node/361112

Answer (score 0):

System settings will only save the file temporarily, to keep files permanently you will need to process and save the file yourself with `file_save()`.

You can save the file (fid) with `variable_set()`, and use `variable_get()` followed by `file_load($fid)` to load your file.

Here is a code example (link to source below):

```
<?php
function custom_settings_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['files'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Files'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['files']['custom_file_1'] = array(
    '#title' => t('File 1'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_file_1', ''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://custom/',
  );

  // Perform our custom submit before system submit.
  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_settings_form_submit';
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
?>
```

And the custom submit:

```
<?php
function custom_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  // Load the file via file fid.
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['custom_file_1']);
  if ($file) {
    // Change status to permanent.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    // Save.
    file_save($file);
    // Optionally record that the module (e.g. user module) is using the file.
    file_usage_add($file, 'user', 'user', $user->uid);
  }
}
?>
```

See https://www.drupal.org/node/1090198 for full explanation and code examples.

Comment: How can we do the same in Drupal 8